# Ive been trying to code in c using VSCODE and cant get it to work

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, g++

So im trying to setup VSCODE to code in c, but i cant seem to get it working. The main problem is that it does not recognize "g++". Im only trying to run a "hello world" program so it should be easy. I downloaded MingW and set it to my PATH. Ive installed C/C++ compiler.

This is my task.jsson file:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [      
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${workspacefolder}\\hello.c",
            "-o",
            "${workspacefolder}\\hello.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "isDefault": true,
            "kind": "build"
        },
        "detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe\""
    }
]
```

}

And the error messages i get are: "g++ : The term 'g++' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:82

- ... OneDrive\Desktop\CLIPS\VS CODE CODE.vscode" ; if ($?) { g++ hello.c ...
- ```
                                                            ~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (g++:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need more info lmk and ill add it to the original post. thank you.

Comment: Why is `g++` relevant to compiling C code?  It is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler.  You need to use `gcc` to compile C code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the PATH included in the environment variables is correct?
It should include the bin folder in the PATH as such:

```
C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin
```

Don't forget to Restart your computer if you change the PATH.

And also have you installed the C/C++ extension from the extensions tab?

To check if your compiler was installed properly open the command prompt and type:

```
g++ -v
```